# How do I accept an image by clicking a button and turning the button into the image selected using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am preparing a sign up page which lets the user insert a photo by selecting a source in their client. The button must convert to the image selected.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use javasript and CSS

```
$('#button').click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('HasImage'))
        {
            $(this).addClass('RemoveImage').removeClass('HasImage');
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).addClass('HasImage').removeClass('RemoveImage');
        }
    });
```

**CSS**

```
.HasImage{background: url('path of image') }
.RemoveImage{background: url('path of image')}
```

Comment: Just one question, how do I obtain the path of the image the user selects?

Comment: $("#buttonId").val() will have the path